# Why the Hover does not work? This code is for displaying social network icons in my web site

Tags: html, css, hover, mousehover

look at my html code and tell me why the Hover does not work? This code is for displaying social network icons in my web site. I use a:hover {color:red;} but it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.socialNetIcons {
    background: url(newiconset4.png);
    height: 30.5px;
    width: 30.5px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {color: red;}
#facebook {background-position: 0px 0px;}
#linkedin {background-position: 0px -30.5px;}
#aparat {background-position: 0px -61px;}
#instagram {background-position: -30.5px 0px;}
#youtube {background-position: -30.5px -30.5px;}
#yahoo {background-position: -30.5px -61px;}
#twitter {background-position: 61px 0px;}
#telegram {background-position: 61px -30.5px;}
#rss {background-position: 61px -61px;}
#google {background-position: -91.5px 0px;}
#skype {background-position: -91.5px -30.5px;}
#behance {background-position: -91.5px -61px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="socialNet">
    <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="socialNetIcons" id="facebook"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://instagram.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="socialNetIcons" id="instagram"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="socialNetIcons" id="twitter"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://plus.google.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="socialNetIcons" id="google"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://linkedin.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="socialNetIcons" id="linkedin"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="socialNetIcons" id="youtube"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://telegram.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="socialNetIcons" id="telegram"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://skype.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="socialNetIcons" id="skype"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://aparat.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="socialNetIcons" id="aparat"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http:/mail.yahoo.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="socialNetIcons" id="yahoo"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://rss.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="socialNetIcons" id="rss"></div>
    </a>
    <a href="http://behance.net" target="_blank">
        <div class="socialNetIcons" id="behance"></div>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should

```
a:hover > socialNetIcons {
  color: red
}
```

instead of

```
a:hover {
  color: red
}
```

a:hover for all text but not icon inside it.

Comment: I see your icons inside a tag are image, so you can't  change color for them.

Comment: @shp as I say above, your icons are image, so you can't change color for them

Comment: Do you know any other way to do this? I really want to change the color of image when hover.

Comment: @shp you should try svg instead of png, svg is light and can change color by css, or you can use "font icons" like font awsesome (http://fontawesome.io/)

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand about font icons, what are these? How should I use this?

Comment: @shp font awesome as a sample, you import link cdn of font, and call icon like this <i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>, name of icon get from http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Comment: Thanks I get it. But now how does it connected to hover??

Comment: @shp you can style hover as normal, a:hover {color: red} to change icon inside a tag to red when hover :)))